# How can I choose a random row in an SQL table and insert something there?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm in a project in Microsoft SQL server. It requires me to put a string directly into a random row.
Making this clear: I have one table. Column 4 has all its 300 rows initialized to NULL.
I have 6 different strings that I want to put in those 300 rows ramdomly.(just in column 4)

How I do that? I've been trying nd I still can't figure this out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is entirely too vague. Have a look at [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/).

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the rows randomly and then use modulo arithmetic to assign the values:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set col4 = v.val
    from toupdate join
         (values (0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'f')
         ) v(n, val)
         on seqnum % 6 = v.n;
```

Comment: Sorry, I have some questions.  toupdate is the name of the column? I know that WITH must have a query name in front, or at least I think so, so I'm not quite getting that part. Also what does the n mean in v(n, val)?

Comment: @BeatrizCastroAlves . . . `toupdate` is a CTE.  `seqnum` is a column.  Similarly, `n` and `val` are names of columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make use of the `RAND()` function in some way in SQL Server for this purpose.